# Why does changing font size mess up default HTML button styling?

Tags: html, css

I am using the default HTML button styling (not allowed to use bootstrap or other kits). When I use the default font size the button looks and acts nicely. However, when I change the font size to 30px, the button becomes darker, loses its round edges, and behaves aesthetically displeasing when clicked.

Why does changing font size mess up the HMTL default styling, and is there any way around this without rebuilding the button styling from the ground up? I have to develop in chrome by the way.

Thanks

Edit: all I am doing is changing the font size of a default button.

HTML

```
<button id='my-button'>Hello</button>
```

CSS

```
#my-button {
   font-size: 30px;
}
```

And this is the difference when I change font size
[image]

Comment: Can you add the code which you are trying to change?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine in Chrome on Windows (see example below). Make sure you don't have any other styles applied to your buttons.

```css
button:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I mean, coloring, border radius, and color when clicked all act differently on the larger button

Comment: Can you add your code or a screencast to your question? For me the buttons behave completely similar.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same as OP, I'm using Chrome - https://i.gyazo.com/d66388a962327007ea3005f926f5c07e.png

Comment: Ah ok, that rather looks like a problem with your OS... I've only tested on Windows and that was fine...

Comment: Yeah macOS Sierra here

Comment: Interesting, must be a OSX, Windows problem